# Apache2 redirect to another local server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have two webservers on my local nework:

192.168.1.1 -> main apache2
192.168.1.2 -> secondary apache2

all http requests come in on port 80 to .1 how can I create a virtual host setting to redirect a subdomain (say lights.example.com) to the server at .2?

Right now I have this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName lights.example.com
        RewriteEngine     On
        RewriteRule       ^(.*)$        http://192.168.1.2$1  [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

but when I browse to lights.example.com I get an 403:

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

from my primary server, but browsing directly to my secondary works fine.

Thanks!
Nat

Answer (score 1):

We use apache to "proxy" the requests instead.  This may be of use?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin admin@example.com
 ServerName application.test.example.com
    # if not specified, the global error log is used
 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/application.error.log
 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/application.access.log combined

 HostnameLookups Off
 UseCanonicalName On
 ServerSignature On

 ProxyPass / http://forwardedserver.internal/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://forwardedserver.internal/
</VirtualHost>
```